# Error while writing a file using internal storage in android

Tags: android, file-io, android-file

I am writing a file on internal storage using the following code:

```
String FILENAME= filename;

FileOutputStream f= openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

but it shows an error that the method `openFileOutput` is undefined for my file. I have no clue why is this happening. I am using the code provided in android developer's forum.

Comment: Adding more of the code for context will help and/or a link to the forum post of the code you are trying to copy.

Comment: Are you using this in `Fragment` or `Activity`?

Answer (score 1):

This method `openFileOutput()` is available from the `Activity` or `Context` classes. In either case you must have an instance of the class for accessing the method.

Where do you run this code?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be missing an `import java.io.FileOutputStream`.  If you are using Eclipse to edit your code, the key combination  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> will add missing imports to the current file.

Comment: Then could I suggest you edit the original question and replace the current code block with the contents of the whole file :)

Answer (score 0):

Import     **import java.io.FileOutputStream**. It will work